# 'Invalid filter clause' while using 'ReceivedDateTime' in GRAPH API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a script to read a mailbox every 1hr and download its attachments. I am following [this][1] python tutorial
Below is my code to get emails for the day

```
def get_all_msg(self):
    endpoint = "/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge '2022-10-05T08:40:20Z'"

    request_url = f'{endpoint}'

    inbox_response = self.user_client.get(request_url)
    return inbox_response.json()
```

This gives the following error

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': 'Invalid filter clause', 'innerError': {'date': '2022-10-06T09:40:20', 'request-id': '4b76e1be-6f5b-45b6-90e7-c374673b3543', 'client-request-id': '11281235-f9a1-4dbc-a9e4-bedd85d46145'}}}
```

Not sure whats wrong.
Any help is appriciated
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad

Comment: Please try the date/time value without single quotes. Something like `$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2022-10-05T08:40:20Z`.

Comment: Also, the name of the property is `receivedDateTime` and not `ReceivedDateTime`.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for pointing it out. It works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with Gaurav comment ,when you use the time in '' it will consider as string , so you need to use without single quote , could you please try with API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2022-10-05T08:40:20Z

[image]

Please see the docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter
[image]

Hope this helps
Thanks